# Help will be greatly appreciated: I'm trying to find the JSON or ABI for one of my contract wallets:

Tags: wallets, keystore

i have lost the keystore to my wallet which i am trying to retrive. As i understand that if i have a Contract associated with that wallet(which i do) i could import the contract and then save the wallet files. If this is true i can get hold of my lost wallet again. But i do not understand the method of retrieving the jason interface if someone can help me actually generate that. My Contract Address is: 0x5246E70a8839987FC4A752746755673382a6c9F1 and the wallet i am trying to retrive is: 0xC137c13da76a1E2E85C66d75599802e887E655DB

Please Help
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by save the wallet files? What kind of contract?

Comment: I just created a simple contract without even understanding how it works when i created my first ethereum wallet. now that i have lost my keystore i want to retrive my wallet. in simple words i dont have the keystore file of my wallet, but i remember the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your keystore is lost forever unless you can find a way to un-delete your files. The keystore is simply encrypted with a password, it is not computed from your password. Having a contract doesn't change anything unless your assets are in the contract and there is a failsafe to extract the assets from the contract. In which case you can make a new account and move your assets into the new account.

Comment: ohh i c, so i lost all the ethereums in that wallet i suppose. well thank you sir for taking the time to help me. greatly appreciate it.